# Convert Hex/Binary/Base64 to IP address in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hex, ip-address, encode, bytea

How can we convert BYTEA datatypes to an **IP address** in INET or TEXT/VARCHAR in Postgres?

Tried all the ENCODE(), DECODE() with 'hex', 'base64' combinations with no luck.

For context, in MySQL, we can use INET6_NTOA('some hex') to get an IP address.

I'm aware there's an INET type in Postgres, but I'm okay with either casting the result to INET type or TEXT/VARCHAR type, as long as it shows (both IPv4 and IPv6)